# extracting region codes out of filenames and joining to a region dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, loops, join

This is my first question, so sorry if it doesn't follow the correct etiquette etc. I am trying to join a dataframe with filenames, to a dataframe with region codes. Most of the filenames contain the correct region code. However, the filenames are messy and contain the region code in random places, along with other random text. But in general, the region itself should either be in the filename just once, or not at all.

```
regions <- data.frame("region_names" = c("Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "Arizona", "California"),
                      "region_codes" = c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA"))


files <- data.frame("filenames" =  c("202101 US AK- Report1", "202101 - PV Report2 AL", "202101 AR - Report3", "202101 - AZ - Report4", "202101 - NY - Report5"))


library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

#expected output

#filenames                 region codes    region names
#1 202101 US AK- Report1      AK              Alaska
#2 202101 -PV Report2 AL      AL              Alabama
#3 202101  AR - Report3       AR              Arkansas
#4 202101 - AZ - Report4      AZ              Arizona
#5 202101 - NY - Report5      N/A             N/A
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are your files in a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to akrun's solution: instead of deframing and matching we could use a `left_join`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

files %>% 
  mutate(region_codes = str_extract(filenames, paste0("\\b", paste(regions$region_codes, collapse = "|"), "\\b"))) %>% 
  left_join(regions, by = "region_codes")
```

This returns

```r
               filenames region_codes region_names
1  202101 US AK- Report1           AK       Alaska
2 202101 - PV Report2 AL           AL      Alabama
3    202101 AR - Report3           AR     Arkansas
4  202101 - AZ - Report4           AZ      Arizona
5  202101 - NY - Report5         <NA>         <NA>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you ill give this a go :)

Comment: Ok I have updated the problem. I forgot to mention that the region codes are not located in the same place each time in the filename, so that complicates things somewhat? Any ideas? Thanks :) – versb just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: And they are very messy and contain other two letter strings

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract` to extract the code and then do a matching with the other data

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
files %>% 
     mutate(region_codes = str_extract(filenames,
              str_c("\\b(", str_c(state.abb, collapse="|"), ")\\b")), 
       region_names = deframe(regions[2:1])[region_codes])
               filenames region_codes region_names
1  202101 US AK- Report1           AK       Alaska
2 202101 - PV Report2 AL           AL      Alabama
3    202101 AR - Report3           AR     Arkansas
4  202101 - AZ - Report4           AZ      Arizona
5  202101 - NY - Report5           NY         <NA>
```

Comment: Awesome. I am not familiar with the deframe function so I will have to get my head around this one. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok I have updated the problem. I forgot to mention that the region codes are not located in the same place each time in the filename, so that complicates things somewhat? Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: I just created exactly the same pattern. :-)

Comment: @MartinGal we cannot do anything on that as there is only couple of options for that :=)

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'm still finding the balance between too much, and too little detail. :) Have updated again.  the filenames are messy, and also contain other two letter strings that would get picked up by the pattern I think. Is there a way to just look for the matching regions

Comment: @versb The only way this can be sorted is from a avector of state abbreviations.  i..e from `state.abb`